# Combining to plotted function

Tags: plotting

I have defined two plots which i would like to combine

```
hist= Labeled[Histogram[{data}, {classWidth},"ProbabilityDensity",LabelingFunction -> Above, ImageSize -> {820, 530}, PlotRange -> All], {Rotate["Relative", 90 Degree], nameAxisX}, {Left, Bottom}]
```

and

```
plot = Labeled[Plot[PDF[HalfNormalDistribution[theta], x], {x, 0,Round[Max[data], 1]}, ImageSize -> {820, 530},PlotRange -> All], {Rotate["Density", 90 Degree], nameAxisX}, {Left,Bottom}]
```

I tried it with

```
Show[hist, plot]
```

but this failed.

Any tips to correct it?

Comment: Remove `Labeled`.  How would you expect the labels to get combined?  `Show` only combines `Graphics`, `Legended` graphics, and stuff that directly converts to graphics (such as graphs, mesh regions, etc.)

Comment: Ok, thanks..i will try

Comment: Is Overlay[{hist,plot}] that for which you are looking?

Comment: It has worked. The problem has been the LABEL. many thanks for your help

Comment: Which worked?  Could you post the answer?

Comment: If you got it to work, please consider answering your own question.